# Constructing Active Directory entry using PowerShell works in IIS 6 but not IIS 7

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7, powershell, adsi

The following line of PowerShell works with IIS 6 installed:

```
$service = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC")
```

However, with IIS 7 it throws the following error unless the IIS 6 Management Compatibility role service is installed:

```
out-lineoutput : Exception retrieving member "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd": "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
```

My goal is to modify the HttpCustomHeaders:

```
$service.HttpCustomHeaders = $foo
```

How can I do this in an IIS-7-compliant way?

Thanks

Comment: This is intended behavoir - the whole point of IIS 6 Management Compatibility is to allow you to manage IIS 7 with IIS 6 scripts.

Comment: I agree, however, it's better to use the MWA namespace or the PS snap-in. Using ADSI via System.DirectoryServices can pollute the applicationHost.config file with work-arounds. For example AboCustomerMapper objects get created when manipulating scriptmaps. These can cause headaches in the long term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this using `APPCMD` and C#/VB.NET/JavaScript/VBScript:

> [Custom Headers  (IIS.NET)](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders)

To do this using PowerShell and the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")

$serverManager = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager

$siteConfig = $serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
$httpProtocolSection = $siteConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol", "Default Web Site")
$customHeadersCollection = $httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders")
$addElement = $customHeadersCollection.CreateElement("add")
$addElement["name"] = "X-Custom-Name"
$addElement["value"] = "MyCustomValue"
$customHeadersCollection.Add($addElement)
$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

This will result in a `<location>` path in `applicationHost.config` with the following:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Custom-Name" value="MyCustomValue" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

To do this in PowerShell using the new IIS 7 [PowerShell Snap-In](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/447/managing-iis-with-the-iis-70-powershell-snap-in/):

```
add-webconfiguration `
   -filter /system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders `
   -location "Default Web Site" `
   -pspath "IIS:" `
   -value @{name='X-MyHeader';value='MyCustomHeaderValue'} `
   -atindex 0
```

This will configure a `<location>` path in `applicationHost.config` with the following:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="X-MyHeader" value="MyCustomHeaderValue" />
                <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The back-ticks at the end of each line indicate a line continuation. The two examples given above were tested on Windows 2008 Server SP2.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an IIS 7 PowerShell snap-in:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/428/getting-started-with-the-iis-70-powershell-snap-in/